# Errors lost during redirect in Prestashop

Tags: prestashop

I have overridden the Prestashop ordercontroller.php file.

There is a switch statement in it which performs certain tasks based upon the number of step we are in.

When i am on step 1 i need to go back to step 0 if there are certain errors. Now if i redirect to the step 0 the errors i set get lost. I am setting errors as below.

```
if(some condition)
{
      $this->errors[] = 'There is an error';
      Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=order');
}
```

What i think happens is that prestashop generates a new request in the redirect and the errors set in the controller are lost. Now there is an other option to change the step and the switch statement but as a case statement is already being executed it seems impossible to me how to switch the step.

Example code:

```
  switch($step)
  {
       case 0:
              //load the step 0
              break;

       case 1:
              //load the step 1
              checkforerrors();
              break;

       case 2:
              //load the step 2
              break;

       case 3:
              //load the step 3
              break;
  }
```

Now the function checkforerrors() in step 1 want to shift to step 0.

Answer (score 1):

Even though this question is quite old, it might help somebody:

The redirect created by PrestaShop is a 302 (HTTP) redirect which causes the browser of the user to request a different URL as a completely new request. That is the reason for the errors of the old request being lost.

Switching between the steps of the PHP switch statement is not possible (AFAIK), but you could simply move the code from the step 0 case into a dedicated method. So, if you encounter any error in step 1, you simply invoke the method containing the relevant code of step 0 just like it would happen if you would actually be in step 0.